# Cassandra | AttributeError - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_up'

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh, amazon-keyspaces

I have two structurally identical tables in a Cassandra database. They are both in the same keyspace. I need to move data from one table to another. I create a standard **CSV** file using `COPY/TO` and now I want to upload the content using `COPY/FROM` inside of another Cassandra table. However, I get the following error:

```
Failed to import 1926 rows: AttributeError - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_up',  given up after 1 attempts
Exceeded maximum number of insert errors 1000
```

*What did I use?*

1. cqlsh 5.0.1
2. Cassandra 3.11.2
3. CQL spec 3.4.4
4. Native protocol v4

I used such command to create CSV file in my local machine:

```
COPY "keyspace_1"."table_1" (column_1,column_2,column_3,column_4,column_5,column_6,column_7,column_8,column_9,column_10,column_11,column_12,column_13,column_14,column_15) TO 'test.csv' WITH delimiter=';' AND header=TRUE;
```

The command above created the CSV file without any problem. I don't have a lot of data. The first table has only 1926 entries. A sample of the first 5 lines of the CSV file used to import:

```
column_1;column_2;column_3;column_4;column_5;column_6;column_7;column_8;column_9;column_10;column_11;column_12;column_13;column_14;column_15
a83aaa26-2f0d-11eb-9330-af4bd388f154;a829040d-2f1d-11eb-9a4c-0b934b0a1818;791d6ed2-e5ec-4860-a165-e25b77dcb075;69f2f19a-3647-4719-abea-315fcba0c29b;2020-11-25 12:56:38.676+0000;;False;True;True;Hello!;2020-11-25 12:56:38.676+0000;;;;
a83aaa26-2f0d-11eb-9330-af4bd388f154;ea7d7c94-2f1c-11eb-a27a-0b934b0a1818;c0bc8368-644b-4238-b629-773f7f3163d8;69f2f19a-3647-4719-abea-315fcba0c29b;2020-11-25 12:51:20.466+0000;;False;False;True;dddd;2020-11-25 12:51:20.467+0000;;;;
a83aaa26-2f0d-11eb-9330-af4bd388f154;e702d2d4-2f1c-11eb-ae91-0b934b0a1818;791d6ed2-e5ec-4860-a165-e25b77dcb075;69f2f19a-3647-4719-abea-315fcba0c29b;2020-11-25 12:51:14.625+0000;;True;True;True;d;2020-11-25 12:51:14.625+0000;;;;
a83aaa26-2f0d-11eb-9330-af4bd388f154;e45d01eb-2f1c-11eb-b7a1-0b934b0a1818;791d6ed2-e5ec-4860-a165-e25b77dcb075;69f2f19a-3647-4719-abea-315fcba0c29b;2020-11-25 12:51:10.187+0000;;True;True;True;1;2020-11-25 12:51:10.187+0000;;;;
a83aaa26-2f0d-11eb-9330-af4bd388f154;7da3e5ae-2f0f-11eb-87a2-5120df6c4a8a;791d6ed2-e5ec-4860-a165-e25b77dcb075;69f2f19a-3647-4719-abea-315fcba0c29b;2020-11-25 11:15:14.385+0000;;True;True;True;123;2020-11-25 11:15:14.385+0000;;;;
```

After that, I run the second command which must upload the content to the second table:

```
COPY "keyspace_1"."table_2" (column_1,column_2,column_3,column_4,column_5,column_6,column_7,column_8,column_9,column_10,column_11,column_12,column_13,column_14,column_15) FROM 'test.csv' WITH delimiter=';' AND header=TRUE;
```

What can be the cause of this problem and how to solve it?

I created the first table with the CQL query below. The second table has the same structure.

```
create table table_1 (
    column_1 uuid,
    column_2 timeuuid,
    column_3 uuid,
    column_4 uuid,
    column_11 text,
    column_14 uuid,
    column_12 uuid,
    column_13 uuid,
    column_15 text,
    column_10 boolean,
    column_8 boolean,
    column_9 boolean,
    column_5 timestamp,
    column_6 timestamp,
    column_7 timestamp,
    primary key (
        column_1,
        column_2
    )
) with clustering order by (
    column_2 desc
);
```

*EDIT 1*:

I used such command in terminal:

```
dsbulk load -url '/my_path/data.csv' -h '"my_host"' -port my_port -k 'keyspace_1' -t 'table_1' -header true -delim ';' -m '0=column_1,1=column_2,2=column_3'
```

*ERROR message*:

```
[driver] Error connecting to Node(endPoint=my_host/x.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx, hostId=null, hashCode=7edbe679), trying next node (ConnectionInitException: [driver|control|id: 0x7bfdbb2f, L:/xxx.xxx.x.xx:xxxxx - R:my_host/x.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): unexpected failure (com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ClosedConnectionException: Lost connection to remote peer))
Operation LOAD_20210211-073148-547063 failed: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=my_host/x.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx, hostId=null, hashCode=7edbe679): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [driver|control|id: 0x7bfdbb2f, L:/xxx.xxx.x.xx:xxxxx - R:my_host/x.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): unexpected failure (com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ClosedConnectionException: Lost connection to remote peer)].
   Suppressed: [driver|control|id: 0x7bfdbb2f, L:/xxx.xxx.x.xx:xxxxx - R:my_host/x.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): unexpected failure (com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ClosedConnectionException: Lost connection to remote peer).
     Caused by: Lost connection to remote peer.
```

Comment: Can you provide the schema? or create table statement

Comment: Hello! Can you check my post one more time pls? I added the CQL statement that I used to create tables.

Answer (score 4):

You will want to download the pem file

```
curl https://certs.secureserver.net/repository/sf-class2-root.crt -O
```

Create the truststore

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in /home/ec2-user/sf-class2-root.crt -out temp_file.der
keytool -import -alias new-cassandra -keystore /home/ec2-user/cassandra_truststore.jks -file temp_file.der -storepass amazon -noprompt
```

Set the environment variables

```
ENV javax.net.ssl.trustStore=/home/ec2-user/cassandra_truststore.jks
ENV javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=amazon
```

Configure the driver

```
dsbulk {
   monitoring.csv = true
   batch.maxBatchStatements=1
   batch.mode=DISABLED
   log.maxErrors=-1
}

datastax-java-driver {
  basic {
   request.consistency = "LOCAL_QUORUM"
   request.default-idempotence = true
   }
  advanced {
      schema.enabled = false
      token-map.enabled = false
      prepared-statements.prepare-on-all-nodes = false
      prepared-statements.reprepare-on-up = false
      advanced.netty.io-group.size = 64

      reconnect-on-init = true
      reconnection-policy {
        base-delay = 100 milliseconds
        max-delay = 1 seconds
      }

      ssl-engine-factory {
         class = DefaultSslEngineFactory
         hostname-validation = false
      }
       connection {
          pool {
             local.size = 3
             remote.size = 1
          }
        }
      }
    }

}
```

execute the command

```
dsbulk load -f default-ks-bulk-loader.conf -k aws -t smoketest -url random.csv --driver.basic.contact-points '["cassandra.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9142"]' -m "0=id,1=event,2=data" -u mike -p pass
```

Answer (score 2):

From error it looks like that there is a problem with connection.

But really, it's better not to use cqlsh's `COPY` command - it has a lot of problems, not handling corner cases, etc.  There is a [tool called DSBulk](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/index.html) ([open source](https://github.com/datastax/dsbulk/)) that is specially written for loading/unloading big amounts of data into/from Cassandra/DSE.

To unload data, just execute:

```
dsbulk unload -k keyspace1 -t table1 -url path_to_unload
```

and to load the same data:

```
dsbulk unload -k keyspace2 -t table2 -url path_to_unload
```

if the tables are identical, you may not need to specify any additional parameters - everything will be handled automatically.

P.S. DSBulk is heavily optimized for loading/unloading operations, and has a lot of options, including import/export from/to compressed files, providing the custom queries, etc.

There is a series of blog posts about DSBulk, that could provide more information & examples: [1](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/03/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading), [2](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/04/datastax-bulk-loader-more-loading), [3](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/04/datastax-bulk-loader-common-settings), [4](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/06/datastax-bulk-loader-unloading), [5](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/07/datastax-bulk-loader-counting), [6](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/12/datastax-bulk-loader-examples-loading-other-locations)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I missed one point by not saying that I don't have pure `Cassandra`, but `Amazon Keyspaces`. At the moment, I'm trying to connect to the database through the `dsbulk` and download the data to a `.csv` file. You do not know where and how to specify the SSL certificate (AmazonRootCA1.pem) for the connection? I found in the documentation that you need to configure `.conf` file and then link that file in `-f` ([filename](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/reference/commonOptions.html#commonOptions__dashF)) option. Right?

Comment: everything that could be specified in conf, you can also pass via command-line...

Comment: Could you check my post again, please. I added the command I used in my terminal. This causes an error. I'm not sure, but it seems to me that I need to install the SSL certificate and also pass it in the command.

Comment: In cqlsh I used this [approach](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/programmatic.cqlsh.html) to connect to the database.